# why install dlv failed

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

```
D:\go-vsc>go get github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
# github.com/derekparker/delve/pkg/proc
src\github.com\derekparker\delve\pkg\proc\disasm.go:11:14: undefined: ArchInst
```

> I install the dlv on window 7 64bit, but when I call the above command,It can not install successfully , why and how to install dlv successfully?

```
D:\go-vsc>go version
go version go1.10.3 windows/386
```

Comment: The go you have installed is for x86 windows install for x64 and then install delve for the same version.

Comment: you mean  I install the go verison "go1.10.3.windows-amd64.msi Installer Windows x86-64"? @Himanshu

Comment: yeah ,good ,thx @Himanshu

Comment: @mike Its ok you should select VonC answer. The matter is not about answers. Main thing is your problem is solved.

Comment: @mike Then select Himanshu's answer, whose reference issue seems to be more precise,  from what I understood from Himanshu's comment.

Comment: Okay ,That is all

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is related to [derekparker/delve issue 20](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/20): "Support for 32-bit systems"

Make sure every component (go, vscode, ...) is 64bits.
Go should be from https://dl.google.com/go/go1.10.3.windows-amd64.zip, architecture x86-64, not x86.

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you are getting:

> src/github.com/derekparker/delve/proc/disasm.go:9: undefined: ArchInst

is reported on [github for delve.](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/1083)

Install go for x64 architecture which have installed for x86 on 64-bit operating system. Uninstall go and install again for x64 OS version. Then install delve for same bit architecture.